# Ordenamiento de Seleccion Java

Tags: java

Estoy intentando usar un algoritmo de ordenamiento de selección en mi programa para que al momento de imprimir las matriculas que se ingresaron salgan en orden de menor a mayor, sin embargo estas salen de mayor a menor. Como puedo arreglar eso? Necesito que los numero de las matriculas salgan de menor a mayor.

```
import java.util.*;
public class seleccion{
   public static void main(String[]args){
      Scanner entrada;
      entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner entrada2;
      entrada2=new Scanner(System.in);


      String[] nombre=new String[6];
      String auxnombre;
      int x=0;
      int y=0;
      int[] matricula= new int[6];
      int b=0;
      int a=0;
      int another=0;
      int opcion=0;
      int auxmatricula;
   int min;



      do{
         a++;
         System.out.println("No. de Registro " +a);
         System.out.println("Ingresa tu numero contable");
         matricula[a]=entrada.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Ingresa tu nombre:");
         nombre[a]=sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
         System.out.println("Deseas otro proceso? 1.si 2.no");
         another=entrada.nextInt();

         if (a>=5)
         {
            another=2;
         }
      }while(another==1);


      for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
      {
         min=y;
         for(y=x+1; y<5; y++)
         {

            if(matricula[y]>matricula[min])
            {

            min=y;
            }
            }
            if(x!=min)
            {
               auxmatricula=matricula[y];

               auxnombre=nombre[y];

               matricula[y]=matricula[min];
               nombre[y]=nombre[min];

               matricula[min]=auxmatricula;
               nombre[min]=auxnombre;
            }

      }
      for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
      {
         System.out.println("Numero Contable: "+matricula[i]+ "\n Nombre: "+nombre[i]);

      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Hola @Stephanie. Obtuviste una **excelente** respuesta en [Qué tengo que cambiar para implementar un ordenamiento de selección basado en código de un ordenamiento de burbuja](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/44911/127), donde se muestra con lujo de detalle cómo ordenar de menor a mayor. ¿En qué se diferencia esta pregunta?

Comment: Diferencia en que , segun yo, solo se debia cambiar uno de los simbolos de mayor que, sin embargo no se acomodan :/

Comment: @StephanieBBautista ¿intentaste el código de esa respuesta?

Comment: Si. Pero mi profesora quiere que el programa venga estructurado como este. Ella ya lo habia arreglado cambiando solo uno de los signos , pero ya lo intente y no los esta acomodando de menor a mayor.

Comment: Ya lo arregle xD Gracias ^^